# strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S not found

Tags: c

I am compiling the simple code below, and run it in gdb. I set a break point at the strcpy line, as soon as I run it for the input for instance abc, and then press s, I get the following error:

```
Breakpoint 1, main (argc=2, argv=0x7fffffffdd98) at ExploitMe.c:9
9           strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);
(gdb) s
__strcpy_sse2_unaligned () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:48
48  ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.
```

I am using ubuntu 12.04 AMD64 and gcc 2.15. Any idea?

---

```
main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    char buffer[80];

    strcpy(buffer, argv[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not an error - gdb can't find the source file for the `strcpy` implementation but it will still display the disassembled code.

Comment: yes, I noticed that, but why? and any idea how to solve it?

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted...

Comment: notice that the code compiles well, and run without any error or warning if I do not set the break point in gdb.

Comment: The debugger doesn't have the source. That's all.

Comment: Install the glibc source code, and tell gdb where it's installed (http://www.ofb.net/gnu/gdb/gdb_49.html)
Interesting filename on the source file... ;)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It is completely harmless to ignore these "errors" when debugging.

The error is simply because GDB is looking for the source of the `strcpy` function. Any function in libc that you don't have the source for will you give a similar error, e.g.:

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
```

Then...

```
(gdb) s
5       int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
(gdb) s
__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=4) at malloc.c:2910
2910    malloc.c: No such file or directory.
```

You can always download GNU libc's source and link it with GDB:

```
git clone https://github.com/jeremie-koenig/glibc /opt/src/glibc
```

Then...

```
(gdb) dir /opt/src/glibc/malloc
(gdb) s
5       int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);
(gdb) s
__GI___libc_malloc (bytes=4) at malloc.c:2910
2910              }
(gdb) s
2915          } else if (!in_smallbin_range(size))
```

... which will let you step through `malloc`'s source code. It's not particularly useful, but it can come in handy sometimes.

Comment: Just make sure that you copy the SAME VERSION as you are using on the system. The latest, which is what you get from git clone, is perhaps not what is installed on your system (and may not be the best idea either!)

Comment: Just as a quick reminder, if you are using gdb you can use n (for next) to skip over lines with those function calls.