# Segfault for nested folder call

Tags: c++, linux, segmentation-fault

I'm working on a file crawler in C++ on Linux Ubuntu 16.04. 

 Basically it should go through a directory adding file byte sizes to a linked-list and making new nodes accordingly. So if I have a single folder with several files inside it counts them fine

 My problem is that if I have a folder that has another folder in it I get a segementation fault that when tested with GNU-debugger reads as follows:

> Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
>   __strcpy_sse2_unaligned ()
>       at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S:714
>   714 ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcpy-sse2-unaligned.S: No such file or directory.

According to [stack overflow post 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13978692/strcpy-sse2-unaligned-s-not-found) I need to somehow install a library but there is issues with installing the proper version.

I don't believe that this is my problem because of where the fault occurs, according to debugger it occurs when called inside of a recursive function that should dig into directories and get data. The same functions are called in my main loop to traverse the top level directory and it works fine on single layers, it's when I have nested directories that I have the problem. Attached is the full source code for reference it is a bit long but if called with same arguments the bug should be easily replicable:

```
// Directory crawler
// Written by Kaz

/*
        1) Start at a user provided directory
        2) Descend the file tree while tracking each file
        3) Groups each file by it's size based off user argument
        4) Print a histogram of file sizes in a bin wide groupings
*/

#include<iostream>
#include <dirent.h>
#include<string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
using namespace std;

int binCount = 0; // count of total bins

struct node{
    node* next, *prev;
    int count, name, min, max;
    node(){
        prev = NULL;
        next = NULL;
        count = 0;
        name = binCount;
        min = 0;
        max = 0;
    }
};


node *nextNode(node* previousNode){

        node *nextLink = new node;
        nextLink ->name = binCount;
        nextLink->prev = previousNode;
        nextLink->next = NULL;
        nextLink->count = 1;
        nextLink->min = previousNode->max + 1;
        nextLink->max = ((previousNode->max)*2) + 1;
        previousNode ->next = nextLink;
        return nextLink;
}

void traverseNewDirectory(node * here, char *dirName){
    DIR * nwd;
    struct dirent *dip;
    node * current;
    current = here;
    bool isadirectory,isHidden;
    if((nwd = opendir(dirName))== NULL){
        perror("Can't open derived directory");
        return;
    }

    while ((dip = readdir(nwd)) != NULL){
        isadirectory = false;
        isHidden = false;
        if((dip -> d_type) == DT_UNKNOWN ){
            struct stat stbuf;
      stat(dip->d_name, &stbuf);
      isadirectory = S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode);
        }
        else if((dip -> d_type) == DT_DIR ){
            if((strcmp(dip->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(dip->d_name, "..")) == 0){
                isHidden = true;
                isadirectory = true;

            }
            else{

                isadirectory = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            if((dip-> d_reclen <= current->max)&&(dip->d_reclen >=current->min)){
                    current->count = current->count+1;
            }
            else if(dip->d_reclen < current->min){
                node*temp = current->prev;
                while(temp->prev != NULL){
                    if((dip-> d_reclen <= current->max)&&(dip->d_reclen >=current->min)){
                            current->count = current->count+1;
                            break;
                    }
                    else if(dip->d_reclen < current->min){
                        temp = current->prev;
                }
            }
        }
            else{
                current -> next = nextNode(current);
                current = current -> next;
                binCount++;
            }
        }
        if(isadirectory){
            char *path;
            strcpy(path,dirName);
            strcat(path, "/");
            strcat(path,dip->d_name);
            strcat(path, "\0");
            if(isHidden == true){

            }
            else{
            traverseNewDirectory(current, path);
            }
        }
    }
    while ( ( closedir (nwd) == -1) && ( errno == EINTR) );
}
void printHistogram(node *head){
    node*temp;
    temp = head;
    while(temp!=NULL){
        cout << "[B " << temp->name << "] from  " << temp->min << " to " << temp->max << " : ";
        for(int i = 0; i < temp->count; i++){
            cout << "x";
        }
        cout << endl;
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}
int main(int argc,char *argv[]){
    // Ensures that a valid directory is provided by the cmd line argument
    if (argc != 3){
        if(argc == 1){
            fprintf (stderr, " argc = %d no directory given  \n", argc);
            return 1;
        }
        else if(argc == 2){
        fprintf (stderr, " argc = %d no size given \n", argc);
        return 2;
        }
        else{
            fprintf(stderr, "argc = %d invalid parameters \n", argc);
            return 3;
        }
    }
    DIR * cwd; // current working directory pointer
    struct dirent *cwdP; // pointer to dirent struct
    int binWidth; // variable for the width of the grouping in the histogram
    binWidth = atoi(argv[2]);
    node *first = new node;
    binCount++;
    first->max = binWidth - 1;
    node * current;
    current = first;
    bool isadirectory,isHidden;
    if((cwd = opendir(argv[1]))== NULL){
        perror("Can't open  main directory");
        return 2;
    }

    while ((cwdP = readdir(cwd)) != NULL){
        isadirectory = false;
        isHidden  = false;
        if((cwdP -> d_type) == DT_UNKNOWN ){
            struct stat stbuf;
            stat(cwdP->d_name, &stbuf);
            isadirectory = S_ISDIR(stbuf.st_mode);
        }
        else if((cwdP -> d_type) == DT_DIR ){
            if((strcmp(cwdP->d_name, ".") == 0) || (strcmp(cwdP->d_name, "..")) == 0){
                isHidden = true;
                isadirectory = true;

            }
            else{

                isadirectory = true;
            }
        }
        else{
            if((cwdP-> d_reclen <= current->max)&&(cwdP->d_reclen >=current->min)){
                    current->count = current->count+1;
            }
            else if(cwdP->d_reclen < current->min){
                node*temp = current->prev;
                while(temp->prev != NULL){
                    if((cwdP-> d_reclen <= current->max)&&(cwdP->d_reclen >=current->min)){
                            current->count = current->count+1;
                            break;
                    }
                    else if(cwdP->d_reclen < current->min){
                        temp = current->prev;
                }
            }
        }
            else{
                current -> next = nextNode(current);
                current = current -> next;
                binCount++;
            }
        }
        if(isadirectory){
            char *fullPath;
            strcpy(fullPath,argv[1]);
            strcat(fullPath,"/");
            strcat(fullPath,cwdP->d_name);
            strcat(fullPath, "\0");
            if(isHidden == true){

            }
            else{
            traverseNewDirectory(current, fullPath);
            }
        }
    }
    while ( ( closedir (cwd) == -1) && ( errno == EINTR) );
    printHistogram(first);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `char *path; strcat(path, "/");` What do you expect that to do? `path` is unitialised and contains garbage. So you are writing to a garbage location. `path` needs to point to a valid memory buffer before you attempt to write to it.

Comment: @kaylum I'm sorry please disregard that `strcat(path,"/");` I put that in to test if I concatenated first if that would remove the issue of `strcpy()` malfunctioning. I just editted that line out of my question

Comment: Same thing, though.  `strcpy` does not allocate memory for you.  It expects that you have done it.

Comment: @KazRodgers Huh? Now I just have to change my comment to: `char *path; strcpy(path,dirName);` What do you expect that to do? `path` is unitialised and contains garbage. So you are writing to a garbage location. `path` needs to point to a valid memory buffer before you attempt to write to it.

Comment: @kaylum how can I initialize it then? When I did it in main I didn't have this problem? And I still don't fully grasp why I'm having it now.

Comment: This falls under the category of _Undefined Behaviour_.  Your code might sometimes appear to work...  Until all of a sudden it doesn't.  You generally consider yourself lucky when it _doesn't_, because then you can find what you did wrong.

Comment: Hmmmm I see, so because it is uninitialized it is not guaranteed to always work properly. but in the case of `char* path`. How would I initialize it? doing `char * path = "";` or `char *path = "\0"` gives me warnings. So I feel like that's the wrong way to do it.

Comment: "When I did it in main I didn't have this problem?". If it is the same code then it has the same problem. It's just that the *symptoms* may have been different. That's what Undefined Behaviour means. I can't tell you exactly how to init as I don't really want to read all your code to understand what you intend to do with `path`. But something like this: `char path[MAX_PATH_LEN]` or `char *path = (char *) malloc(MAX_PATH_LEN)`. Don't forget to free the memory in the latter case.

Comment: Ah, just realised you marked this as `c++` code. What I gave you is fine for C. It'll work for C++ too but probably better ways to do it for C++ as explained in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's your fault ;)

The fact that it segfaults in `strcpy` is the immediate giveaway that you have not allocated any memory when constructing the paths (or you don't have *enough* memory for the string, or less commonly that you have heap corruption somewhere else).  So, look at the two places you do this:

```
        char *path;
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcpy(path,dirName);
        strcat(path, "/");
        strcat(path,dip->d_name);
        strcat(path, "\0");
```

You better be allocating enough memory for this.  At the moment, you're just copying a string into an unknown memory location based on the value that you never initialized into `path`.

Really, I don't know why you're writing C-like code in C++.  You're using C++.  So just use `std::string`, which takes care of memory management for you.  Even this would probably do:

```
std::string path = std::string( dirName ) + "/" + dip->d_name;
```

You can then recurse by accessing the C string:

```
traverseNewDirectory(current, path.c_str());
```

There may be other problems with your code too.  I haven't taken the time to read it, but it looks pretty heavy on pointer use, almost devoid of comments, and overly complicated.  All of these are ingredients for trouble.

Comment: I use `char *` to be compatible with the `opendir` and `readdir` system calls. From what I read I need those in order to make it work. and  path is for`traverseNewDirectory(current, path);`. The way it should work is if I have   a folder `test` and I find another directory called `nest1`. Open `test/nest1` and add it's file sizes to the linked list

Comment: Sure, but you also don't appear to understand memory, and this is _not_ how you write C++ code.  I have edited my answer to elaborate on how you can use `std::string` as a drop-in replacement that will work.

Comment: hmmm I receive the following error: `prog2.cpp: In function ‘void traverseNewDirectory(node*, char*)’:
prog2.cpp:117:44: error: invalid conversion from ‘const char*’ to ‘char*’ [-fpermissive]
    traverseNewDirectory(current, path.c_str());`   I think it's because I need to modify the prototype for `traverseNewDirectory()` any advice?

Comment: It's more correct for `traverseNewDirectory` to take a `const char*` because it's not supposed to modify the string.  So you should modify the function definition accordingly.

Comment: I implemented it as you suggested and it works so far. I do have a memory leak in my linked list somewhere to fix but that isn't in the scope of this question. I will work more on it, accept your answer and thank you again for the help.

Comment: No problem.  I'm glad you recognise when it's time to continue working through other problems on your own. =)  Happy coding!